# How to run Ruby gems as apache

Tags: ruby, linux, apache, amazon-ec2, rubygems

On an AWS EC2 amazon linux instance I am getting the error:

```
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- syck (LoadError)
from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from beats-1.3.0/bin/beats:8:in `<main>'
```

when trying to execute a ruby bin as apache. I have set the permissions of html to 777, and I have copied over the installed gems from /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems to /usr/local/share/ruby.

I am aware that this is an issue normally solved with yum install ruby-devel and yum groupinstall development.

An interesting note, is that when I changed the user and group in httpd.conf to ec2-user/ec2-user, I got the same issue. It seems it is not the apache user, but I am stumped.

Comment: I would try to install the gem via `gem install syck` first instead of copying them manually.

Comment: I have done that as well.. going bananas here